# Change the DefaultEntityListenerResolver on Doctrine with ZF2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I am trying to change the Doctrine DefaultEntityListenerResolver without success.
I have the need to call the service manager inside EntityListener defined trought annotation  @ORM\EntityListeners.

So I've coded this ListenerResolver to check if a Listener implements the ServiceLocatorAwareInterface:

```
class ListenerResolver extends DefaultEntityListenerResolver {
private $serviceManager;

public function __construct(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceManager){
    $this->serviceManager = $serviceManager;
}

public function resolve($className){
    $listener = parent::resolve($className);
    if ($listener instanceof ServiceLocatorAwareInterface){
        $listener->setServiceLocator($this->serviceLocator);
    }
    return  $listener;
}
```

}

And to change the Listener Resolver I've created a bootstrap function on my Module.php to change the resolver on DoctrineORMModule:

```
class Module {
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e){
    $serviceManager = $e->getTarget()->getServiceManager();
    $resolver = new ListenerResolver($serviceManager);
    $serviceManager->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default')->getConfiguration()->setEntityListenerResolver($resolver);
}}
```

But I still can't reach the Service Manager, any suggestion?

Comment: Did you find out how to solve this? I am trying exactly the same thing.

Comment: I need to get some business logic done before a specific entity is being saved. But either lifecycle-callbacks nor eventlisteners have possibility to access the servicemanager. Anyways I think lifecycle-callbacks are not the correct place, because injecting stuff into entities is bad practice.

Comment: @ibo_s I found a way to achieve this... I'll post a answer as soon as possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that we don't really need to change the EntityListenerResolver, we only need to register a new behavior. So I registered the listener at the current EntityListenerResolver on the bootstrap.

1- Implement the ServiceLocatorAwareInterface on each entity listener.

```
namespace Application\Business\Entity\Listener;

use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface;

class User implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface {
}
```

2 - Register the entity listeners as Invokables on Module.php.

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'invokables'=>array(
                //EntityListeners
                'Application\Business\Entity\Listener\User'=>'Application\Business\Entity\Listener\User',
                ),    
            )
        )
    )
}
```

3 - Register the listeners at onBootstrap on Module.php, I did that by iterating over the list of invokables and search for the listeners namespaces.

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e){
        $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
        $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
        $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);
        //Inejct the Service Maganer on listeners
        $serviceManager = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
        $entityManager = $serviceManager->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
        //Register the Entity Listeners
        $config = $this->getServiceConfig();
        $invokables = $config['invokables'];
        foreach ($invokables as $invokable){ //Verify the listener namespaces
            if((strpos($invokable, 'Application\Business\Entity') !== FALSE) &&(strpos($invokable, '\Listener') !== FALSE)){
                $entityManager->getConfiguration()->getEntityListenerResolver()->register($serviceManager->get($invokable));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And you are done... You can now freely use $this->getServiceLocator()->get() on listeners...
Hope it helps..

Comment: Be aware that using ServiceLocatorAwareInterface is deprecated now, and is a bad practice to use the service locator inside Listeners. Use factories for dependencies!